# 'No such table' after mounting sqlite in docker container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, sqlite

I have a .net + React.js application and I am trying to conatinerize it. I have succesfully mounted my sqlite database in docker container by using following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapp:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
    volumes:
        - "./Database:/Database"
```

However when I am running the container the error `No such table` occurs. I have installed sqlite3 in my container and I run sqlite3 and the tables with records indeed exist:

```
# cd Database
# sqlite3 MyDatabase.db
SQLite version 3.34.1 2021-01-20 14:10:07
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .tables
Table1              Table2
Table3                 __EFMigrationsHistory
sqlite>
```

.Net application is in directory /app and database is in directory /Database and both of them are on the same level. I really have no idea what might be a problem.

Comment: You could provide a [mcve] with a few more details?  For example, is the application actually looking for a file with an absolute path `/Database/MyDatabase.db`, or is it looking somewhere else?

Comment: The connection string to the files looks like this: `optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Datasource=..\\Database\\FinanceWebAppDatabase.db");` and the structure of created container looks like this: https://ibb.co/YNHBmLr From my understanding it should work just fine but it does not :/ I thought that 'No such table' means that the database was found but after deleting the database the exception is the same so it indeed looks like if the database was in the wrong directory. However as mentioned before I dont see a mistake in my code. https://github.com/ArturMarekNowak/FinanceWebApp/tree/feature/Docker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed my connection string from:

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Datasource=..\\Database\\FinanceWebAppDatabase.db");
```

to:

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Datasource=../Database/FinanceWebAppDatabase.db");
```

Apparently in the first container was looking for a file named '.\Database\FinanceWebAppDatabase.db'